# How can I delete a file upon its close in C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

I wish for a file to be deleted from disk only when it is closed.  Up until that point, other processes should be able to see the file on disk and read its contents, but eventually after the close of the file, it should be deleted from disk and no longer visible on disk to other processes.

Comment: Do you mean all process should be able to see the **name** of the file in its directory?  Because if, as you say, what you need them to see are only the **contents**, then an `rm` of the file's name _does_ leave them usable by all processes who have the file open, and the file does disappear when the last process closes it so that it's not open in any process.

Comment: Yes, must see the name of the file, such that any new process invoked after the deletion sees the file on disk until the original process that deleted the file exits.

Comment: From my understanding of Unix filesystem semantics, this is not possible, at least not without race conditions. You might be able to do something with a periodic job running `lsof`, but that strikes me as a bad idea. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The solutions below using code to delete the file don't seem robust to the process being killed, or the system losing power. Maybe if you created the file in a volatile file system, and had a watchdog process where either process will delete the file if the other process stops, would that be "robust enough?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the file, then delete it *while* it's open. Other processes will be able to use the file, but as soon as all handles to file are closed, it will be deleted.

Edit: based on the comments WilliamKF added later, this won't accomplish what he wants -- it'll keep the file itself around until all handles to it are closed, *but* the directory entry for the file name will disappear as soon as you call `unlink`/`remove`.

Comment: @WilliamKF: You can use either `unlink` or `remove`.

Comment: Sorry, but William says the file name must be visible in the file system. The “delete, but keep it open” strategy will not work for that – it will leave the file there all right, but since the number of directory entries pointing to it (of which there can be more than one!) is zero, no process not yet having it open will find it. (Neither will the other ones see an entry in the file system.)

Comment: @Christopher, William either doesn't completely understands what he wants, or doesn't tell us why he wants to do what he described (`flock`?  watching pidfile?).  Still, I can't imagine any situation where Jerry's answer wouldn't be the solution.

Comment: @Pavel: Unlinking the file from the system does not allow other processes to see it in the file system any more, which is what William, in the second comment below the question, says he wants. But I completely agree that there is probably a better way of achieving the desired effect than to jump through hoops to get a file removed “only when it is closed.” That sounds very much like the kind of problem you only get after thinking yourself into a corner far from where you started (and want to be at the end).

Answer (score 3):

Open files in Unix are reference-counted. Every `open(2)` increments the counter, every `close(2)` decrements it. The counter is shared by all processes on the system.

Then there's a *link count* for a disk file. Brand-new file gets a count of one. The count is incremented by the [`link(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/link) system call. The [`unlink(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) decrements it. File is removed from the file system when this count drops to zero.

The only way to accomplish what you ask is to open the file in one process, then `unlink(2)` it. Other processes will be able to `open(2)` or `stat(2)` it **between `open(2)` and `unlink(2)`**. Assuming the file had only one link, it'll be removed when *all processes* that have it open close it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [unlink](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink)

```
#include <unistd.h>

int unlink(const char *pathname);
```

> unlink() deletes a name from the
>   filesystem. If that name was the last
>   link to a file and no processes have
>   the file open the file is deleted and
>   the space it was using is made
>   available for reuse.
>
> If the name was the last link to a
>   file but any processes still have the
>   file open the file will remain in
>   existence until the last file
>   descriptor referring to it is closed.
>
> If the name referred to a symbolic
>   link the link is removed.
>
> If the name referred to a socket, fifo
>   or device the name for it is removed
>   but processes which have the object
>   open may continue to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you could try [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/), but it looks more like c-style.

Maybe [boost::filesystem::remove](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#remove)?

```
bool remove( const path & ph );
```

> Precondition: !ph.empty()
>
> Returns: The value of exists( ph )
>   prior to the establishment of the
>   postcondition.
>
> Postcondition: !exists( ph )
>
> Throws: if ph.empty() || (exists(ph)
>   && is_directory(ph) && !is_empty(ph)).
>   See empty path rationale.
>
> Note: Symbolic links are themselves
>   deleted, rather than what they point
>   to being deleted.
>
> Rationale: Does not throw when
>   !exists( ph ) because not throwing:
>
> Works correctly if ph is a dangling
>   symbolic link. Is slightly
>   easier-to-use for many common use
>   cases. Is slightly higher-level
>   because it implies use of
>   postcondition semantics rather than
>   effects semantics, which would be
>   specified in the somewhat lower-level
>   terms of interactions with the
>   operating system. There is, however, a
>   slight decrease in safety because some
>   errors will slip by which otherwise
>   would have been detected. For example,
>   a misspelled path name could go
>   undetected for a long time.
>
> The initial version of the library
>   threw an exception when the path did
>   not exist; it was changed to reflect
>   user complaints.

You could create a wrapper class that counts references, using one of the above methods to delete de file .

```
class MyFileClass{

    static unsigned _count;
 public:
    MyFileClass(std::string& path){
     //open file with path
     _count++;
    }

    //other methods

    ~MyFileClass(){

        if (! (--_count)){

          //delete file
        }

     }

    };

   unsigned MyFileClass::_count = 0; //elsewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend your notion of “closing the file” beyond `fclose` or `std::fstream::close` to whatever you intend to do. That might be as simple as

```
class MyFile : public std::fstream {
  std::string filename;
public:
  MyFile(const std::string &fname) : std::fstream(fname), filename(fname) {}
  ~MyFile() { unlink(filename); }
}
```

or it may be something much more elaborate. For all I know, it may even be much simpler – if you close files only at one or two places in your code, the best thing to do may be to simply `unlink` the file there (or use boost::filesystem::remove, as Tom suggests).

OTOH, if all you want to achieve is that processes started from your process can use the file, you may not need to keep it lying around on disk at all. `fork`ed processes inherit open files. Don't forget to `dup` them, lest seeking in the child influences the position in the parent or vice versa.